# Compiled Services Class Has been removed Composer error laravel 5.4

Tags: composer-php, laravel-5.4

Dears whenever i want to add any Packeg using composer i face below error

"Compiled Services Class Has been removed"

I search many solution like "composer update" etc but still i face this problem
due to this error my working is stop.
kindly help me whats the original solution.
thats the composer installation problem? or what ?

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The message `The compiled services file has been removed.` is a info message from the clear compiled command: `php artisan clear-compiled`.

It is called from `php artisan optimize` that runs on every composer update or install.

The message is only a info reporting that the file bootstrap/cache/services.php has been removed.

The services.php file will be reconstructed at the next request.

So at the end its a normal info message.

Comment: you mean to say when i try to install any packeg its just show this info message not effect any packeg installation

Comment: sure I have the exactly same message and my application works fine.

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered the same problem. 
Just remove the "Vendor" folder then install the composer. It worked fine for me.